# Yii2 - Unknown error in renderSelectOptions method when using active dropDownList

Tags: php, yii2

I'm getting an error when the aforementioned method gets called during the use of activeForm's dropDownList. What's weird is that I have already made other dropDownLists in a similar manner and they're working normally.

The error is:

```
PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
strcmp() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
```

The _form code for generating the list is as follows:

```
$lista_unidades = ArrayHelper::map(Unidad::find()->where('institucion="Carabineros de Chile"')->asArray()->all(), 'id_unidad', 'nombre');

asort($lista_unidades);

$form->field($model, 'id_unidad_que_diligencia')->dropDownList($lista_unidades, ['prompt' => 'Seleccione...']);
```

Yii2 provides the following information about the error (links to images):

[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YEaP.png), [Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCnxS.png)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

The Model Class:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\Expression;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "orden_judicial".
 *
 * @property string $id_orden_judicial
 * @property string $causa_rit
 * @property string $causa_ruc
 * @property string $causa_rol
 * @property string $fecha_emision
 * @property string $tipo
 * @property string $estado
 * @property string $id_unidad_que_direcciona
 * @property string $id_unidad_que_diligencia
 * @property string $id_unidad_que_redirecciona
 *
 * @property AdjuntoOrdenJudicial[] $adjuntoOrdenJudicials
 * @property Aviso[] $avisos
 * @property Persona[] $rutPersonas
 * @property Dilgienciamiento[] $dilgienciamientos
 * @property Unidad $idUnidadQueDirecciona
 * @property Unidad $idUnidadQueDiligencia
 * @property Unidad $idUnidadQueRedirecciona
 */
class OrdenJudicial extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
     public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'orden_judicial';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['fecha_emision', 'tipo', 'estado', 'id_unidad_que_direcciona', 'id_unidad_que_diligencia'], 'required'],
            [['fecha_emision'], 'safe'],
            [['id_unidad_que_direcciona', 'id_unidad_que_diligencia', 'id_unidad_que_redirecciona'], 'integer'],
            [['causa_rit', 'causa_ruc', 'causa_rol', 'tipo', 'estado'], 'string', 'max' => 100]
        ];
    }

    public function behaviors() {
        return [
                [
                    'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                    'createdAtAttribute' => 'fecha_emision',
                    'updatedAtAttribute' => false,
                    'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
                ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id_orden_judicial' => 'Número de orden',
            'causa_rit' => 'Causa RIT',
            'causa_ruc' => 'Causa RUC',
            'causa_rol' => 'Causa ROL',
            'fecha_emision' => 'Fecha de Emisión',
            'tipo' => 'Tipo',
            'estado' => 'Estado',
            'id_unidad_que_direcciona' => 'Tribunal o Fiscalía',
            'id_unidad_que_diligencia' => 'Unidad Policial',
            'id_unidad_que_redirecciona' => 'Unidad que Redirecciona',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getAdjuntoOrdenJudicials()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AdjuntoOrdenJudicial::className(), ['id_orden_judicial' => 'id_orden_judicial']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getAvisos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Aviso::className(), ['id_orden_judicial' => 'id_orden_judicial']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getRutPersonas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Persona::className(), ['rut_persona' => 'rut_persona'])->viaTable('aviso', ['id_orden_judicial' => 'id_orden_judicial']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getDilgienciamientos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Dilgienciamiento::className(), ['id_orden_judicial' => 'id_orden_judicial']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getIdUnidadQueDirecciona()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Unidad::className(), ['id_unidad' => 'id_unidad_que_direcciona']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getIdUnidadQueDiligencia()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Unidad::className(), ['id_unidad' => 'id_unidad_que_diligencia']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getIdUnidadQueRedirecciona()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Unidad::className(), ['id_unidad' => 'id_unidad_que_redirecciona']);
    }
}
```

And the Controller Class with the relevant action:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\OrdenJudicial;
use app\models\OrdenJudicialSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;

/**
 * OrdenJudicialController implements the CRUD actions for OrdenJudicial model.
 */
class OrdenJudicialController extends Controller
{

    (...)

    public function actionCreate()
    {

        $model = new OrdenJudicial();

        $model->estado = "En Creacion";

        $idUnidadQueDiligencia = Yii::$app->getUser()->identity->getIdUnidad();

        $model->id_unidad_que_diligencia = $idUnidadQueDiligencia;

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_orden_judicial]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    (...)
}
```

Comment: Could be the content of $list_unidades....

Comment: i wanted to know what  field 'nombre' contains. is it integer , string or whatever @scaisEdge

Comment: You coudl have  some quotes inside the name....

Comment: @scaisEdge in the second image you can see that $lista_unidades contains at the moment: [3 => 'Comisaria de Bulnes', 4 => 'Comisaria de la Pintana', 1 => 'Tenencia de Quiriquina']

Comment: Just a question.. have you tried without `asort` ?

Comment: @scaisEdge I have, there's no difference.

Comment: please show also the model and the related controller...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be your `id_unidad_que_diligencia` si an object an not a single value.

```
$idUnidadQueDiligencia = Yii::$app->getUser()->identity->getIdUnidad();

$model->id_unidad_que_diligencia = $idUnidadQueDiligencia;
```

try chech this situation using

```
var_dump($model->id_unidad_que_diligencia)
```

then if is not a flat string value adjust you code for gettin the proper value.

Comment: This helped me to solve the problem. Instead of setting `id_unidad_que_diligencia` there, my intention was to set `id_unidad_que_direcciona`. The app would crash due to trying to add another value to `id_unidad_que_diligencia` when it was already set. Thanks!

Comment: @Ignaciovl Is a good news. At first I could not understand that the problem was not the dropdown list but the value of the field. I rate your question as useful because in not an easy question..